# Java IntelliJ: Change existing class usages to a new class

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

In Java Spring Boot using IntelliJ, how do I refactor existing class usages to a different class? I don't want to rename an existing class, but migrate to a new class. For example, change `Fruit` to `Automobile` class,

This reference does not help, https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/rename-refactorings.html#rename_class_example

Comment: I'm not quite sure if I understand you correctly but does Shift + F6 not do what you want? Here is the reference from JetBrains -> https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/rename-refactorings.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use "Type migration" refactoring, see [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/type-migration.html)

Answer (score 1):

The problem, as you know, is that all usages of your class are linked to it in IntelliJ. You can solve this by relinking all the usages to the new class.

Say you have ClassA and ClassB. You want to move all usages of ClassA to use ClassB.

Step 1 - rename ClassA to ClassATemp. Make sure to not use Shift-F6 for this, i.e. don't use IntelliJ's refactoring rename. Just change the text. Do the same for the filename. Now you have successfully changed ClassA to ClassATemp, and your code is completely broken. Hurray!

Step 2 - rename ClassB to ClassA. During this step, links to ClassA will "re-establish", but with the new class. You may need to reimport everything to the new package, or alternatively change the package as well (might be more of a hassle).

Step 3 - re-rename the newly renamed ClassA back to ClassB. Make sure to do this using IntelliJ's refactor. All links will now follow.

Final step - re-rename ClassATemp to ClassA.

Answer (score 0):

On the toolbar:

`Edit` -> `Find` -> `Replace in Files...`

Comment: however, will that add in the correct imports for the all the files using it ?

Comment: Well, in one run, most likely no.  You might have to do several search and replaces to get everything properly changed.

Comment: ok, I thought there was an easy way in Intellij, without several search and replaces

Comment: There very well might be any easier way, I just do not know of any.  Depending on how many classes you're changing, hopefully it won't be too much work.  I just had to do a find and replace for the `java.validation` to the `jakarta.validation` package name change.